# Using kurtosis to assess significance of components from independent component analysis

Tags: statistical-significance, pca, kurtosis, independent-component-analysis

In PCA eigenvalues determine the order of components. In ICA I am using kurtosis to obtain the ordering. What are some accepted methods to assess the number, (given I have the order) of components that are singificant apart from prior knowledge about the signal?

Comment: I actually think that in ICA you can still use the number of 'significant' (ie, 90% of energy) eigen-vectors, as the number of independent components.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing this question still lacks an answer, I'd like to reiterate, as [@Tarantula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8763/tarantula) commented, an accepted method to select assess the number of components retained is through the explained variance. You retain $K$ components given a criterion from the *a priori* whitening PCA and perform ICA on those components.

<sub>I don't know of any accepted method to do this kind of assessment with the kurtosis, this question might be unanswerable in it's fully.</sub>